# ERROR_PROC_NOT_FOUND on PInvoke call to SendMessageW

Tags: c#, windows, pinvoke

I need to automate a third party program, and the only course of action is to simulate a click on some buttons.

I do this by finding the HWND handle of the button with `EnumChildWindows`. When I've found the "window" (the button), I try to send [`BM_CLICK`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775985.aspx) to it with `SendMessageW`. This works, my tests show that the button indeed think it was clicked.

The problem arise in my error handling. There is no feedback given by the `BM_CLICK` message, so I don't really know if it has been clicked. I thought I should be diligent and check for any error codes though with [`Marshal.GetLastWin32Error`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getlastwin32error.aspx).

This returns `ERROR_PROC_NOT_FOUND`, which is not really what I would expect from a successful message handling.

I import `SendMessageW` as follows:

```
[DllImport("User32.dll", 
           CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, 
           CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi, 
           SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr SendMessageW(
     HandleRef hWnd, 
     UInt32 Msg, 
     UIntPtr wParam, 
     IntPtr lParam);
```

The code doing the call is:

```
User32.SendMessageW(
    buttonHandle,
    (uint)ButtonControlMessages.BM_CLICK, // value of BM_CLICK = 0x00F5.
    UIntPtr.Zero,
    IntPtr.Zero);

int error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
if (error != ErrorCodes.ERROR_SUCCESS) // love the name of this error code.
    throw new Win32Exception(error);
```

My tests are just using a simple Windows Forms with a button control attached. Thus, I can procure the handle through `button.Handle`. It gets clicked; could it be that this error is completely unrelated?

It sure would be nice to get rid of it though, I'd like some way to be sure that the call to `SendMessageW` at least didn't fail.

*I'm on Windows 7 x86-32 with .NET 4.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The calling convention should be `Stdcall`, but since that is the default you can just drop it.

I think your SendMessage P/Invoke looks a bit odd but that's probably not the cause of the issue. In any case I would do it like this:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
```

I think what's happening here is that `SendMessage()` is working but isn't assigning the last error.  The only thing that the [documentation for `SendMessage()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644950%28VS.85%29.aspx) mentions about errors is:

> When a message is blocked by UIPI the last error, retrieved with GetLastError, is set to 5 (access denied).

The return value for `SendMessage()` is dependent on the message sent. In the case of `BM_CLICK` there is apparently no message sent. In other words you simply do not get any feedback.

Comment: Thanks for the help, didn't know it added a W automatically. Sadly the other changes did not correct it, it exhibits exactly the same behaviour. `SetLastError = False` makes no difference either. Could it be Windows Forms doing something strange?

Comment: I am running the tests through the ReSharper xUnit runner, and it made `Marshal.FreeHGlobal` totally weird in debug mode, so perhaps this is another oddity due to the environment. I'll know more when I can run this outside the tests.

Comment: I've updated my answer, I think I have a better idea of what is going on.

Comment: Ok thanks, this seems plausible. It's just not doing anything and I get a resident error code, right?

Comment: @Skurmedel That's right. In fact I've just checked this in native code and my hypothesis appears to be correct.

Comment: Thanks. Here's your 15 rep :)